# Dart indexed_db put() error

Tags: dart, indexeddb, dartium

The following code throws Internal Dartium Exception.

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/dart">

    import 'dart:html';
    import 'dart:indexed_db';
    import 'dart:math';

    Random random = new Random();

    void main() {
      window.indexedDB.open('myDB', version: 1, onUpgradeNeeded: _initDB).then((Database db) {
        Transaction transaction = db.transaction('myStore', 'readwrite');
        ObjectStore objectStore = transaction.objectStore('myStore');
        Map data = {
          'id': 'id' + random.nextInt(1000).toString(),
          'name': 'name' + random.nextInt(1000).toString()
        };
        objectStore.put(data);
      });
    }

    void _initDB(VersionChangeEvent e) {
      (e.target as Request).result.createObjectStore('myStore');
    }

  </script>
  <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

I filed an issue to http://www.dartbug.com/14256, but maybe something is wrong in my code?

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the error you are getting?

Comment: Yes, here is it http://www.dartbug.com/14256

Comment: What kind of object is MAP? I quess that will be the issue. Probably the map object can't be serialized properly.

Comment: If I try to put some other types, I get "unsupported object type for conversion" error. So, I guess, Map is the only type I can use.

Comment: you can't just use the var keyword instead of MAP?

Answer (score 1):

The referenced bug suggests that this was an error, but the error message was now useful. It should not report a more useful message:

> Uncaught Error: DataError: The object store uses out-of-line keys and has no key generator and the key parameter was not provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```dart
void _initDB(VersionChangeEvent e) {
    (e.target as Request).result.createObjectStore('myStore', autoIncrement: true);
}
```

But you will need to clear the data from your browser in your settings for the new structure to work (or possibly increase the db version number).